# How to make an alias for an existing type in Apple Swift?

Tags: swift

In C++, I do  `using A = B;` to make an alias.
How would I do this in Swift?

Answer (score 9):

From the [Apple's manual](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-XID_424):

```
typealias AudioSample = UInt16
```

Exactly same with C++ stuff.